# PowerShell script with messagebox don't show on remote computer

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This is my script:

```
$name = function Get-Name {
    $env:computername
}
Get-Name

$time = function Get-SystemUptime {
    $operatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
    "$((Get-Date) - ([Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($operatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)))"
}
Get-SystemUptime

$string = Get-SystemUptime
$separator = "\."
$string.Split($separator, 2)

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$days = $string.Split(".")[0]
if ([convert]::ToInt32($days, 10) -ge 1) {
    $MsgboxTxt = "TXT $($days) TXT"
    $MsgboxTitle = '!!! TXT !!!'
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MsgboxTxt, $MsgboxTitle, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Stop, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button1, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions]::DefaultDesktopOnly)
}
```

I start it with this command on remote computer by my company program who runs it with batch (CMD) administration rights:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File uptime.ps1
```

When I run in on local computer by copy file and run it from CMD in local priveliges it's OK. Everything working fine.

I think my company program (LOGSystem) runs it on administration user, not logged user.

Is there a option to run it on logged users using CMD command or else?

Comment: You CANNOT mess with other users. It it's shown but hidden from anyone logged on.

Comment: Maybe I can run it as "runas" if I know user and password?

Comment: No windows is designed to stop you. You can start programs but you cannot see them

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this script for? Why must it run in the context of another user?

Comment: Script is to check uptime of remote computer and if it is more then 5 days then send a MessageBox to make restart at the end of  the day/work. MessageBox need to show at current logged user to let him see it.

Comment: Maybe it will be good to convert it to EXE, xcopy it and add schedule task in windows to run it once?

Comment: @fosfik : why use an exe when you can just schedule powershell.exe with the scriptfile as a parameter. There is however a way to send something to the GUI of another use (though it requires Windows 10) : toast messages. The requirement of a toast message is however that a user is logged on to the machine (but as soon as any user is logged on I can send toast messages to that machine). Not the best approach for your case though...

Comment: Nah... I have more then a 1000 computers ;/ Theres only a 50% with windows 10...

Comment: I found solution to use psexec and login on remote computer with logged user login and password.